# Db2 Procedure to get minimum set of records from each table

Tags: db2

I have a scenario as I need to read a table(consists only one column with 1000 records) as a procedure1 & to pass that value to another procedure2.On that second procedure it should accept the value (table name) from procedure1 & I need to query some set of records from all the tables.I can do this as a program.Thing is that I need to do all these as db2 procedures itself. As, I am new to these procedures unable to figure it out.

Sample snippet of code will be appreciated.

Kindly help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: DB2 documentation provides examples of stored procs. Unless you show us what you have tried, we have no idea what you need to know that isn't already in the documentation. As far as we know, any examples we might have won't show how to do it any better than the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to define "cursor with return to caller" in one procedure, and use the associate and allocate in the second procedure.

http://www.sqlines.com/db2-to-oracle/process_result_sets_in_procedures

Comment: Thanks for the reply. as u said I followed the steps on the link. I cant find any output.Could u please elaborate some detailed, as I am beginner on these procedures

Answer (score 0):

These are my procedures:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DUMMY2 ()
    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
P1: BEGIN
    -- Declare cursor
    DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CALLER for
    SELECT TBNAME FROM VENKATASD.META_DISTINCT;
    -- Cursor left open for client application
    OPEN cursor1;
END P1
```

Procedure2:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DUMMY3 (OUT P_TBNAME VARCHAR(100))
    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
P1: BEGIN
    DECLARE result RESULT_SET_LOCATOR VARYING;
    -- Declare cursor
    -------DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR WITH RETURN for-----
    CALL DUMMY2();
    ASSOCIATE RESULT SET LOCATOR(result) WITH PROCEDURE DUMMY2;
    ALLOCATE cur CURSOR FOR RESULT SET result;

    FETCH cur INTO P_TBNAME;
    -- Cursor left open for client application
    CLOSE cur;
END P1
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong. I don't find any output on the console. This is my output screen:

```
Run: VENKATASD.DUMMY3(VARCHAR(100))
{call VENKATASD.DUMMY3(?)}

Run of routine completed successfully.
Query execution time => 20 ms
```

Comment: This really should have been an edit to the question, not an answer.

Comment: You are not getting values because the first cursor is opened for the second procedure, and you cannot send those values back to the caller. You should get the values (insert them in a temporary table) and open a cursor on that table to the caller.